# How to set the specific android monkey test?

Tags: android, android-camera, monkeyrunner

I want to do the frequent operations about the the camera. The frequent operations are consist of launching camera -> taking picture -> doing onBackPressed -> launching camera -> ...

Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an interesting example to demonstrate the use of **[AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient)** and how they can simplify such a task.

Run (using the long options to be self-explanatory):

```
culebra --start-activity=com.google.android.gallery3d/com.android.camera.Camera \
    --verbose --verbose-comments \
    --find-views-with-content-description=on \
    --output myscript.py
```

Once culebra finishes, `myscript.py` contains the *autogenerated* script. This script will start **Camera** and try to find all the Views. One of these Views is the **shutter** button, the one we would like to touch to take a picture. It's something like

```
# class=android.widget.ImageView
no_id29 = vc.findViewWithContentDescriptionOrRaise('Shutter button')
```

Edit the autogenerated script and add at the end (your **Camera** application may be different, just check the generated script to see if your values are the same as mine)

```
no_id29.touch()                                # take the picture
vc.sleep(3)                                    # wait a bit
device.press('BACK', MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP) # exit
```

Save it.

That's it!, run `myscript.py` and all the steps will be done.
You can add a loop inside the script if you want to repeat it many times or even run `myscript.py` inside a loop in the shell.